# MongoDB Query many-to-many equivalent with Grails MongoDB plugin

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have two classes mapped with [MongoDB Grails PLUGIN](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) like that:

Class Person:

```
class Person {
     static mapWith="mongo"

     String name
     String email

     static hasMany = [profiles: Profile]

     static belongsTo = Profile


     String toString(){
        return name +" - " + (profiles)
}   }
```

And Class Profile:

```
class Profile{

static mapWith="mongo"

String abbreviation
String description
static hasMany = [people: Person]



String toString(){
    return abbreviation + " - " + description
}}
```

How can I make a query to return people per profile with finders provided by mongo?

A mongo query may be useful too!

This finder doesn't return anything

```
def people = Profile.findAllByAbbreviation("example").people
```

Sorry the english...

Comment: Profile.findAllByAbbreviation("example")*.people ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class Person {
     static mapWith="mongo"

```
 String name
 String email
List<Profile> profile= new ArrayList<Profile>();

static embedded = ['profile']
```

}